# Custom rewrite from URL to URL using slug

Tags: url-rewriting

I don't know if it is possible to achieve this. I want to create custom rewrite rule to redirect an URL to other one.

For now, my URL is like :

```
/store-director/storeName-directoreName/
```

I want my URL to be like :

```
/store/storeName/directorName
```

I tryed something like this :

```
add_rewrite_rule('^store/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','store-director/$matches[1]-$matches[2]','top');
```

It doesn't work, it redirects to an other page...

Comment: You need to rewrite one url or multiple?

Comment: Multiple URL with dynamic storeName and directorName.

Comment: How many urls? more than 1000?

Comment: Almost 50 URL to rewrite

Comment: What is `/storeName-directoreName/`? Is that the slug of a page?

Comment: Yes it is. From now, I add automaticly the slug of the parent to the slug of child page using a function.

Answer (score 0):

You could load a csv file to [Simple 301 redirect plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) with the url's you want to rewrite. It's simple to use and works.